# emme:emma get the following error (Jenkins)

Tags: maven, jenkins, emma

I'm running a job that instrumant Code Coverage on a jenkins machine Server
The job is running the command: emme:emma 
and keep failing when it try to download dependencies from the maven repo:
you can see the following log:

```
    INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of External-Central has elapsed or updates are forced.
          Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to External-Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2):
          Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
          Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
          Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of External-Central has elapsed or updates are forced.
          Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to External-Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2):
          Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
          Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
          Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of External-Central has elapsed or updates are forced.
          Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to External-Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): 
          Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
          Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
          Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
```

Thanks in advance 
Nir

Comment: are you behind a firewall that refuses connection to Maven central?

Comment: yeah, i needed to open a proxy connection to those urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer to the close the loop here :

Please ensure that you are not behind a firewall that refuses connections to Maven Central